Do I need to erase the SSD (1TB) before I try to boot from a USB with ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso installed using rufus?
Do I need to erase the SSD (1TB) before I try to boot from a USB with ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso installed using rufus?
2017 intel I7 ACER Spin 3, w/1TB SSD
The USB Boot is taking a long time (100 mins so far)
Got to Launching  'EFI\boot\bootx64.efi" ...

You can TRY a Ubuntu ISO without any changes to an existing/installed system, so there is no need to erase or prepare anything... eg. I often use borrowed hardware to Quality Assurance test unreleased ISOs/images; where by nothing is changed on the borrowed system (outside of clock settings in some cases that is easily corrected; windows uses local time where Ubuntu uses internet/UTC time).

This question is similar to: Try Ubuntu 20.04 without installing. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Is this expected? The initial USB Boot is taking a long time (100 mins so far) The boot is stuck at " Launching 'EFI\boot\bootx64.efi' ... "

No; though there are cases where due to firmware bugs on machines, booting an ISO on external media (such as thumb-drive) can take >10 minutes (including, though rarely an hour) .. but that only impacts external/install media and not once installed. Your issue maybe ISO or ISO write related. Did you verify your ISO after download (ensure it's valid), and use updated rufus or a CLONE write method (otherwise failure to boot if you used options to reformat ISO on non-update media can be expected; but that is user created due to poor options for your hardware); or validate ISO write?

rufus is an app that allows you to reformat an ISO during the write, so you must use options that match your hardware, and updated rufus for the ISO you're using - otherwise don't make format changes to ISO during write (ie. just CLONE or no-change write of ISO to media; I think it's called dd-mode on rufus but sorry I don't use that app).

No, I did not verify the ISO after download, I'll do that. Also I'll use the balena etcher suggested in the instructions. I'll post my results after that is completed.
